auth wrapper or session in route handlers is returning as undefined in Next-Auth v5 (beta)
I'm encountering an issue with authentication in Next.js API routes when using NextAuth.I'm trying to secure my API routes so that only authenticated users can access them. However, it returns undefined with an auth wrapper or session
import { auth } from "../../auth"

export const POST = auth((req) => {
  // req.auth -- undefined
})

or
export const POST = async (req) => {
  const user = await session();
  console.log(user) // undefined

});

I also tried getting token inside routes but it is also not working
so I want a better way how can I make secure API routes for role based scenarios using token or session.

The reason it was returning undefined for the session was because I was  calling API from the server component. It's working using client component and to use it with a server component, you must pass next-headers in headers when making an API call.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This worked for me.
const getSomethingById = async (id: string) => {
    const sessionCookies = cookies().getAll();

    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://localhost/api/something/' + id, {
            headers: {
                Cookie: sessionCookies.map((cookie) => `${cookie.name}=${cookie.value}`).join('; '),
            }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Failed to fetch');
        }

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error fetching:', error);
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

You may utilize the example provided below
import { auth } from "../auth"
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"

export const POST = async(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const session = await auth(req, res)
  if (session) return res.json('Success')
  return res.status(401).json("You must be logged in.");
}

For further details, please refer to: https://authjs.dev/guides/upgrade-to-v5?authentication-method=api-route
